# Can we add logo to HTML5 Video?

Tags: html

I'm customizing HTML5 video to suit the web application I'm building. Would like to know if there is any chance we can add / embed our own logo to the video control.

Please suggest or send me the reference links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I figured out the solution myself. It could be achieved using videojs library watermark plugin. The source can be downloaded from the below link.

**https://github.com/xbgmsharp/videojs-watermark**

Customization and beautification of other controls can also be done easily.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve a permanent watermark that can't be removed, you should render the watermark directly to the video file, but that will be really intensive for the [GPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_card). You can of course use HTML, JavaScript or CSS to add a watermark, but it can be removed by modifying the source files.

For example, how easily user can remove the watermark:

[image: Image of "how to remove watermark"]

I don't know in what environment you are working but you can render text inside a video using Node.js paired with [FFmpeg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg) and [Jimp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp).

Answer (score 0):

yes, there are many ways to achieve it, depending on what you need, but here you have a very nice and easy to follow tutorial explaining EXACTLY what you need (and then some more) [see tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-custom-html5-video-player--pre-8905)

Comment: I followed this tutorial.. but it didn't work. Have you tried it before? If so, please share the link so that I can have a look at it.

Comment: no, I didn't use that exact example, but something similar of my own and I can't show my work online. Anyway, since you're having issues with this, here's a tip: remember html5 video is basically html5 + css so simply be sure to give a class or id to the container (better if you have the controls in a separate container) and give it a position:relative value. Then add your logo and position it position:absolute and whatever distance you need (like 10px right 5px bottom for right of controls). If you can manage basic CSS, it's really easy

Comment: I have already tried that too. But, the issue would arise when the video is maximized the logo stays just there.

Comment: just make sure you're adding the logo INSIDE the controls container and it will be always relative to it. For example:

#control{position:relative; width:100%; height:30px}
.logo{position:absolute; width:40px; height:20px; position:absolute; bottom:5px; right:5px;}

and then
`<div id="control">your controls here.... <img class="logo" src="yourimage.png" alt="" /></div>`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
  .video-container {
    position: relative;
  }

  .video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button
  {
    display: none !important;
  }

  .watermark {
    position: absolute;
    left: 3%; top: 3%;
    color: white;
    animation: 15s moving-watermark infinite;
  }
</style>
<body>

  <div id="vid-cont" class="video-container">
    <video class="video" controls>
        <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010`enter code here`/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type='video/mp4' id='mp4'>
    </video>
    <i class="watermark">My logo[enter image description here][1]</i>
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).